# How to make ubuntu run as one screen on both laptop monitor and TV

Tags: xorg, display

I'm using my TV as a monitor to watch movies on my laptop, which is running 13.04, and I was wondering: how I can make it show my laptops screen on both my TV and laptop?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is *Mirroring*:

1. Click your user in the upper right corner of your screen.
2. Click System Settings.
3. Type `display` and hit enter.
4. **Make sure the TV is connected**
5. There should be a tick button that says "Mirror Display", activate it.

Now you should read this answer in both your TV and the Laptop Monitor.

Comment: Great answer! But between step 4 and 5 should be another step. Something like: *There should be a button that says "Detect Displays", click on it*.

Answer (score 0):

Install arandr. Then run it. Place both desktops in the same space, covering each other. :)
If looking for a command line alternative, use xrandr.