# Ubuntu connection to TV problem

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, tv

one problem. I was planning on watching a football match with my friends the other day, and i connected my laptop to the TV (we were streaming the match). So, what i thought would happen, was that i thought the content on the screen of the laptop will be projected onto the TV screen. But what happened was i had a totally independent workspace, desktop, or how it's called properly, on my TV, with the match playing on laptop only.
How can i set my laptop to project it's screen onto the TV?

edit: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: Just drag the window of the player/browser (whatever plays it) to the second screen(TV), then expand it full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `SUPER + P` (Super is WINDOWS KEY)

If this doesn't works try with `sudo apt-get install arandr` and then open the screen layout editor you just installed with `arandr`command.
Once you opened it you could place the second screen above the first to do the mirroring:

[image: Mirroring on Ubuntu]

Once you've dragged the second one over the first one (DVI-I-1 over DVI-I-0 in my case) you could save it with the check mark (✓)

Done, you've just mirrored your screen. Have fun watching footbal on TV with your friends!

*Psst! Have you tried by simply dragging the football match window on the second screen?*

Answer (score 1):

If having the same display on your laptop and your TV really is what you want, you can set up mirroring – see the linked answer: [How to make ubuntu run as one screen on both laptop monitor and TV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327655/how-to-make-ubuntu-run-as-one-screen-on-both-laptop-monitor-and-tv/327680#327680)

Mirroring has the drawback that not all resolutions are necessarily available. Therefore, I'd suggest dragging the stream to the TV.

If you felt like the TV was inaccessible, you just have to make sure you find the right "connection" to exit one screen and enter the other. Usually, you just move the mouse to the right and see it disappear on one screen while it reappears on the second. However, if your second screen has a lower vertical resolution than your first screen, not all of your left screen's right edge will be aligned with your second screen. (This is visualized in this discussion: https://superuser.com/questions/281176/mouse-gets-stuck-in-lower-edge-of-screen-on-portrait-oriented-window)

Also note that your TV most likely will be initially aligned to your laptop monitor's right edge, regardless of where your TV is physically located.