# Custom dual screen configuration buggy

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, xrandr, tearing

Using Ubuntu's system settings to configure two screens (desktop monitor and TV via HDMI in my case) is not ergonomic.

Hence I decided to code a handy switcher script which lets me choose between mirrored output ("mirror") and either left screen on/right screen off or left screen off/right screen on ("switch"). It is based on `xrandr`.

**It works as expected and I like the flexibility when using `xrandr`, BUT:**

- **tearfree setting** necessary for TV output is either *ignored* or *ineffective* after using my script (Why?)
- **system settings** are *broken* after using my script: If I change screen configuration via system settings afterwards, *output will be scrambled*.

**My script must be doing something horribly wrong. How can I make it work correctly?**

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DESKTOP="DP1" # desktop monitor
DSIZE="1280x1024"

TVPORT="HDMI1" # connection to TV
TVSIZE="1920x1080"

SCALE="1.5" # e.g. 1920/1280

if xrandr | grep "$TVPORT" | egrep "\)$"
then # TV port is turned OFF => turn it on
  selected_mode=`echo -e "mirror\nswitch" | zenity --list --text="Choose Mode:" --column="Mode"`
  if test "$selected_mode" = "mirror"
  then
    xrandr --output "$TVPORT" --auto --left-of "$DESKTOP" --output "$DESKTOP" --panning "$TVSIZE"
    xrandr --output "$DESKTOP" --scale "$SCALE"x"$SCALE" --mode "$DSIZE" --fb "$TVSIZE" --panning "$TVSIZE"
  fi
  if test "$selected_mode" = "switch"
  then
    xrandr --output "$TVPORT" --auto --output "$DESKTOP" --off
  fi
else # TV port is turned ON => turn it off
  xrandr --output "$TVPORT" --off --output "$DESKTOP" --mode "$DSIZE" --fb "$DSIZE" --scale 1x1 --panning "$DSIZE"
fi

exit 0
```

[Tearfree](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Tear-free_video) which works when using Ubuntu normally, but not after running my script:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "SwapbuffersWait" "true"
   Option      "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: <b> <a href="http://askubuntu.com/questions/327655/how-to-make-ubuntu-run-as-one-screen-on-both-laptop-monitor-and-tv"> Here</a> is something tricky me be it helps you any way</b>

Comment: <b> <a href="http://askubuntu.com/questions/327655/how-to-make-ubuntu-run-as-one-screen-on-both-laptop-monitor-and-tv"> Here</a> is something tricky me be it helps you any way</b>

Comment: In your link's target question, `arandr` is mentioned. Thanks for the hint. Maybe `arandr`'s source code can tell me the correct solution.